# How do I check the mAh or Voltage for my laptop battery?

Tags: battery, power, voltage

I was wondering if there's an easy way I could find out the mAh for my laptop battery, It's a Lenovo Yoga 12 and it states on the manufacturers website that the battery is a Li-Polymer 8-cell 47Wh but there's no information on the battery voltage so I can't convert the 47Wh to mAh. I' like to know because I'm buying a powerpack and want to know the mAh for comparison.

Comment: [Try this](https://milliamps-watts.appspot.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use HWMonitor - http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html

It will give you detailed battery info:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[BatteryInfoView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/battery_information_view.html) from trustful source who wrote a lot of useful and unique utilities.(Not affiliated, just happy user :) )

It doesn't requiring installation, works as standalone program.

[image: ![Battery_Info_Viwer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/batteryinfoview.gif)]

If you're on linux, then directory `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0` will tell the same info (but in linux way) or if you have installed package `upower` then use
 `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0` to see result in human readable text